# Parsing JSON array stored in SQL Server object using SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to get the value of an JSON **array** using SQL

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(CAST([JSON_Field] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '$contactDetails.name') 
FROM users
```

I am getting all NULL values.

Comment: contactDetails[
   {"DateCreated":"2015-11-08",
   "DateModified":"2017-01-23",
   "name":'John',
   "Id":"b325b4"}
   ]

Answer (score 0):

As you have provide any sample, so i just put an example that may help to you

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=' [{"Jobs":[{"Agricultural":false,"AlternateTitle":null,"DateInJob":"/Date(1454997600000)/","DirectLabor":false,"EffectiveDate":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","EmployeeIdentifier":{"EmployeeNumber":"000001","CompanyCode":"60639"},"EmployeeType":"REG","FullOrPartTime":"F","HourlyOrSalaried":"S","JobCode":"HRCOORD","JobGroup":null,"LocalUnion":null,"NationalUnion":null,"OrgLevel1":null,"OrgLevel2":null,"OrgLevel3":null,"OrgLevel4":null,"PayFrequency":"B","PayGroup":"60639","PayScaleCode":null,"Project":null,"Promotion":false,"ReasonCode":"100","ScheduledHours":80,"Seasonal":false,"SelfServiceProperties":null,"ShiftCode":"Z","ShiftGroup":"Z","StepNo":null,"Supervisor":null,"TimeClock":null,"Transfer":false,"YouthTraining":false}],"CompanyCode":"60639","EmployeeNumber":"000001","FirstName":"George","LastName":"TestEmployee"},{"Jobs":[{"Agricultural":false,"AlternateTitle":"Client Care Representative","DateInJob":"/Date(1497592800000)/","DirectLabor":false,"EffectiveDate":"/Date(-62135575200000)/","EmployeeIdentifier":{"EmployeeNumber":"003613","CompanyCode":"60637"},"EmployeeType":"TES","FullOrPartTime":"F","HourlyOrSalaried":"H","JobCode":"CCREP","JobGroup":null,"LocalUnion":null,"NationalUnion":null,"OrgLevel1":"000","OrgLevel2":"001","OrgLevel3":null,"OrgLevel4":null,"PayFrequency":"B","PayGroup":"60637","PayScaleCode":null,"Project":"STAFF","Promotion":false,"ReasonCode":"Z","ScheduledHours":80,"Seasonal":false,"SelfServiceProperties":null,"ShiftCode":"Z","ShiftGroup":"Z","StepNo":null,"Supervisor":{"EmployeeNumber":"003639","CompanyCode":"60637","ExtensionData":{}},"TimeClock":null,"Transfer":false,"YouthTraining":false}],"CompanyCode":"60637","EmployeeNumber":"003613","FirstName":"George","LastName":"TestEmployee"}]'

    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
    WITH (
        LastName nvarchar(100) N'$.LastName',
        FirstName nvarchar(100) N'$.FirstName',
        Jobs NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    ) j1
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(j1.Jobs)
        WITH (
            ScheduledHours INT '$.ScheduledHours'
        )
    ) x
```

Comment: The JSON is stored in a sql object field. I can access the entire JSON string but I need a specific value

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
declare @json2 nvarchar(max)=N'[{"DateCreated":"2015-11-08", "DateModified":"2017-01-23", "name":"John", "Id":"b325b4"}]'

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@JSON2)
WITH (
    [name] nvarchar(100),
    [DateCreated] nvarchar(100) 
) j1
```

Have a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the json fragment you posted in the comments:

```
{
    "ContactDetails": [{
        "DateCreated": "2015-11-08",
        "DateModified": "2017-01-23",
        "name": "John",
        "Id": "b325b4"
    }]
}
```

you can read the outer element with `openjson`, then you can parse the content of the inner array using `cross apply` and another `openjson`, this time specifying name and data type for each column you want to read:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{"ContactDetails":[ {"DateCreated":"2015-11-08", "DateModified":"2017-01-23", "name":"John", "Id":"b325b4"} ]}'

select s.* 
from openjson(@json)
with (
    [ContactDetails] nvarchar(max) as json
) t
cross apply(
    select *
    from openjson(t.ContactDetails)
    with (
        [Id]           nvarchar(50) '$.Id',
        [name]         nvarchar(50) '$.name',
        [DateCreated]  date         '$.DateCreated', 
        [DateModified] date         '$.DateModified'
    )
) s
```

Result:

[image]